# New database table best practice: Magento DB or a new DB?

Tags: magento2, database, table

I've added a new "Installation" info tab on the product details page so we can add installation information for each product.

I don't want future Magento upgrades to destroy new tables I create so should we add a new table into the existing Magento db or create a separate db for custom tables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have your tables inside Magento db.
An upgrade should not destroy custom tables.
Usually upgrades add/remove stuff from core tables.
Or add more core tables.
You should be safe when doing an upgrade.